# Parse.com getObjectById return nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, objectid

First I retrieve the IDs of all my objects, then I try to get a specific object by its ID, but it returns nil, despite the retrieving process always a success.

```
func getObjectID () {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Main")

        // get the actual data
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil || objects == nil {

                println("Error retrieving data")

            } else {

                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for object in objects {

                        self.objectsID.append((object.objectId)!)
                    }
                println(self.objectsID)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

The above process always succeeds and when I print the IDs it shows exactly as they are on Parse.

```
func retrieveData () {

var objectID: String = objectsID[0]

println(objectID) // <- Success!

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Main")
        // get the actual data
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectID)// <- Problem here {
            (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil || object == nil {

                println("Error retrieving data, \(error)" ) // Stops here and gives an Error!

            } else {

                //Some code
            }
        }
    }
```

The process of getting the `ObjectID` is always a success, and when I print it, it always shows perfectly, but somehow it doesn't work, the app gives me this error:

```
Error retrieving data, nil
```

But when I type the actual Id itself like this: `"ZXolF5cdip"` the object gets successfully retrieved. Any ideas  ?

Comment: Is your code shown above exactly as in your project ?  You need to call `getObjectInBackground(objectId block:...)`, not `getObjectInBackground(objectID)`

Comment: tried that, no difference.

Comment: Can you  update your question to show your actual code?

Comment: Is your app really crashes or just printing out the error message? And you cannot query for objectId this way, you have to create a pointer object which has the objectId, and use that object in the query.

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't crash it just gives an error when trying to query. :)

Comment: Have you checked if `objectsID[0]` actually holds a value? I have the suspicion that it does not hold an objectId which leads to an empty result. As you said, when you hardcode the ID it works.

Comment: I already said it does in my code.